# Выглядеть (как?), (каким?)

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Итак. Есть ли разница в предложениях «он выглядел недоумённо» и «он выглядел недоумённым»? Как по мне — да. Во втором предложении акцент делается на том, что он, этот человек, чего-то не понимает, что-то он недопонял, но первый же вариант описывает, что он, этот человек, выглядит как-то странно; допустим, вырядился необычно — так, что вызывает только вопросы и недоумение. И вообще — возможен ли вариант «он выглядел недоумённым» сам по себе? Это правильно? Так говорят? Просто если я имею в виду именно то, что человек что-то недопонял и поэтому он выглядит недоумённым, то я ведь могу сказать так? Это не будет считаться ошибкой? Надеюсь, я доходчиво объяснила суть вопроса.

Comment: Во втором случае можно сказать ещё "недоумевающим". (Мне больше нравится этот вариант, но, возможно, это из-за того, что мало сталкивался с вашим.)

Comment: Если в ответе есть полезная информация - можете нажать на верхний серый треугольник. Если ответ решил проблему - поставить зелёную галочку (она может быть только у одного ответа). https://i.imgur.com/jnvr8HZ.png При этом отвечающие понимают, что не зря старались и что их ответ кому-то помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что Вы правы в своей оценке, то есть  существует разница между состоянием человека и впечатлением, которое он производит. Поэтому мы говорим: он выглядел веселым, но не говорим: он выглядел весело (для окружающих).

С другой стороны, конкретное выражение ***выглядел недоумённым*** практически  встречается редко, а выражение ***выглядел недоумённо***, скорее всего, неверно.

1) **Когда используется прилагательное?**

В этом случае мы говорим о  внутреннем состоянии кого-либо.

Он выглядел недоумённым (недоумевающим), также: подавленным, потерянным.

Рыжий вяло кивнул. Он ***выглядел подавленным,*** кривил губу, не знал, куда деть руки. На суде ***он выглядел потерянным:*** он никогда не дрался в автобусах и не понимал, как это с ним случилось.

Вариант ***выглядел недоумённым*** (недоумевающим) в Нацкорпусе не встречается. Вероятно, по одному внешнему виду это состояние сложно определить, **оно должно как-то проявляться в действии.**

2) **Когда используется наречие?**

Обычно **наречие относится к глаголу** и характеризует действие. Можно ***недоуменно*** спросить, взглянуть, пожать плечами, то есть как-то выразить недоумение.

В сочетании ***выглядел уныло, подавленно, странно*** речь идет   не о состоянии лица, а о производимом им **впечатлении на окружающих**.  Так чаще говорят о неодушевленных предметах.

Без него кабинет **выглядел уныло.** Храм стоял с куполом, при кресте. **Не выглядел уныло.** Сейчас библиотека **выглядела уныло.** Он **выглядел странно** (вызывал странное чувство).

Вариант ***выглядел недоумённо***  в Нацкорпусе не встречается.

Из словаря:

НЕДОУМЕНИЕ,  Состояние, вызванное непониманием, неясностью чего-л.

НЕДОУМЕВАТЬ, недоумевающий; Испытывать недоумение, находиться в состоянии недоумения.

НЕДОУМЕННЫЙ; (разг.) НЕДОУМЁННЫЙ,  1. =Недоумевающий. **Стоять потерянным и недоуменным.** Н-ое выражение лица. Недоумённо, нареч. Н. смотреть, слушать.

Answer (score 2):

«Выглядеть» не сочетается ни с наречием «недоуменно», ни с прилагательным «недоуменным». Можно «смотреть, глядеть, взглянуть» как? Недоуменно. Может быть «недоуменный взгляд». Ближайший синоним — «растерянно».

Comment: А "недоумевающего вида", по-вашему, тоже не может быть? Грамота говорит, что это одно и то же.

Comment: Артем,  в вопросе этого нет, поэтому нет и в ответе

Comment: Ну хорошо — нет, но мне-то вы можете ответить?

Comment: С недоуменным видом —вполне нормально,  но к глаголу "выглядеть" это никак не относится.

Comment: Согласен с V.V., оба варианта в вопросе режут глаз. "Недоумевающий вид" - вполне нормально. "Озадаченным"/"озадаченно" возможно подойдут вместо "недоумённым/недоумённо".

Answer (score 1):

Разница в постоянстве качества.

Сравнить:

*Он выглядит глупо.* // Глупо на данный момент - временное качество.

*Он выглядит глупым.* // Глупый как особенность - постоянное качество.

Примечание: второй вариант стилистически плохо звучит, в отличие от первого.